# TFS 2017 Test plan: navigate to test cases within suite

Tags: tfs, test-plan

According keyboard shortcuts in TFS test plan there is no option for go to specific test case in test plan (ex. search by ID and select line with this test case). Is there any option for search test cases like it realised for example in excel (Ctrl+F)?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2017, you can try below ways to filter the test cases:

1. Add tags for test cases, then filter the test cases by tags.

   Click `Filter Test Plans` button -->> Change value to `Microsoft.TestCaseCategory` -->> add/delete clause based on you requirement -->> Run the filter to get the needed test cases. (Reference below screenshot)
2. In browser (eg Chrome or IE), navigate to the specific test suite,
   then `Ctrl + F`, enter the `test case ID` or special information of
   the specific test case.
3. Create `New query-based suite`, then `Edit query` to query out the
   needed cases.

[image]